# Zsh redirect to /dev/null and pipe

Tags: zsh, io-redirection

From [this](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html) I understand that `&> /dev/null` in zsh redirects both `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`. Hence,

```
echo a &> /dev/null
```

gives no output.

However, when I do

```
echo a &> /dev/null | cat
```

cat will print the `a`, where I expected it to print nothing.

What is going on here?

Comment: How about reading further down - section 7.2 Multios ?

Comment: Similar to: [How can I pipe only stderr in zsh?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/265061)

Answer (score 6):

As don_crissti already mentioned, this is the default behaviour of `zsh` and can be switched off with `unsetopt multios`.

Also see the manpage of `zshmisc`.

Comment: follow up question: why would you ever redirect all output to `/dev/null` before piping it to another program?

Comment: @Ragnar `/dev/null` is just a file as any other, and redirection to a file and at the same time to a terminal is very common practice. Zsh cannot guess what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Ragnar: you probably can answer that question on your own.

Comment: @Thomas, it seems to me that `echo a &> /dev/null | cat` is equivalent to `echo a 2> /dev/null | cat` (because we don't care about the `a` being sent to `/dev/null` anyway, right?), so why not use that instead

Answer (score 4):

> Note that a pipe
>   is an implicit redirection; thus
>
> `date >foo | cat`
>
> writes the date to the file ‘foo’, and also pipes it to cat.

From here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html.

Thus, with `multios` option `echo a &> /dev/null | cat` is equivalent to `echo a 2>1 | tee /dev/null | cat` in other shell, like `bash`.